# ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID when using Next Image with external URL

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, next.js, next.js13

I have a custom domain with a subdomain pointing to an AWS S3 bucket like `images.domain.com`. I am able to have the user upload an image and see it in the bucket. I can access the image using the URL generated and this URL is also in the user's data in the DB.

When I try to use this URL as a `src` in Next Image I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11576:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  cause: Error [ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID]: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: Host: images.domain.com. is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com, DNS:*.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com, DNS:s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com, DNS:*.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com, DNS:s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com, DNS:*.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com, DNS:*.s3.amazonaws.com, DNS:*.s3-control.us-west-1.amazonaws.com, DNS:s3-control.us-west-1.amazonaws.com, DNS:*.s3-control.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com, DNS:s3-control.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com, DNS:*.s3-accesspoint.us-west-1.amazonaws.com, DNS:*.s3-accesspoint.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com, DNS:*.s3-deprecated.us-west-1.amazonaws.com, DNS:s3-deprecated.us-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

I added my custom subdomain to `next.config.js`:

```
images: {
    formats: ['image/avif', 'image/webp'],
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'images.domain.com',
      },
    ],
  },
```

I can load the image using a standard `<img>` tag, but I would like to leverage the Image component in NextJS. I am running this locally using NextJS 13.5.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S3 Websites **do not support https**. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteHosting.html):

> Amazon S3 website endpoints **do not support HTTPS**. If you want to use HTTPS, you can use Amazon CloudFront to serve a static website hosted on Amazon S3.

As explained in the docs, you have to setup  Amazon CloudFront to have HTTPS.